# control where magento left nav renders

Tags: php, html, css, xml, magento

I want to change where the magento left nav renders so that it is placed AFTER the static CMS block set on a given category, but before the actual category products.

At the moment in catalog_category_layered I've set

```
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
        </block>
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
```

Which puts it at least inside the col-main div, but it still renders above the static CMS (which is output by catalog/category/view.phtml I think?)

I need it to render after that static block because that block is essentially a full width banner.

The current html output is

```
<div class="col-main">
    <aside class="col-left sidebar col-md-3 col-xl-2 col-left-first" style="min-height: 1003px;">
    </aside>
    <section class="category-top"><img alt="" src="/skin/frontend/rwd/thejewelhut/images/cat/pandora.png">
    </section>
    <section class="category-topmobile"><img alt="" src="https://placehold.it/768x300"></section>
    <div class="col-main col-md-9 col-xl-10 category-products">
    </div>
</div>
```

and the desired output would be

```
<div class="col-main">
    <section class="category-top"><img alt="" src="/skin/frontend/rwd/thejewelhut/images/cat/pandora.png">
    </section>
    <section class="category-topmobile"><img alt="" src="https://placehold.it/768x300"></section>
    <aside class="col-left sidebar col-md-3 col-xl-2 col-left-first" style="min-height: 1003px;">
    </aside>
    <div class="col-main col-md-9 col-xl-10 category-products">
    </div>
</div>
```

only a subtle difference but makes all the difference.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put before="-" to the leftnav block:

```
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
    </block>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that leaves it in exactly the same position as it is at the moment.